# LibGDX cannot find font files

Tags: android, fonts, libgdx

I've created label and simple JSON-like skin definition.

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
        white: { r: 1, g: 1, b: 1, a: 1 },
        red: { r: 1, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1 },
        yellow: { r: 0.5, g: 0.5, b: 0, a: 1 },
},
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: {
        medium: { file: medium.fnt }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
    default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white },
}
}
```

and here is the calling code:

```
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skins/label_skin"));
Label label = new Label("SomeMsg", skin);
label.setPosition(100, 100);
stage.addActor(label);
```

Got an error in Eclipse , said following:

**Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Font file not found: medium.fnt**

same with default.fnt

Comment: well do you have the medium.fnt in the same directory like from where the skin is loaded?

Comment: No, thought it is something built-in. Where can I find this font definition file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you like to use  fonts with libgdx you need to include the

```
[FONTNAME].fnt and [FONTNAME].png
```

in your assets folder. You can use [Hiero](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) to generate those files. Just open the GUI, select a font, and save the result to your assets folder.